# Writing a large amount of data from a web service to a file in chunks

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, web-services, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to solve the general situation of receiving a big chunk of data from web services via:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

For small data, I just use:

```
[webData appendData:data];
```

and at the end, in:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

I write it to my file using an output stream.

What about when the data is huge, a couple of MBs of data? In this case, it would be better to dump data in `connection:didReceiveData:` several times to the same file. It sounds easy, using `NSFileHandle`, but syncing for read and write while considering async/non-blocking UI is not straightforward (at least for me).

Any idea what would be a good approach for this case?
I was thinking to use `NSThread`, queueing the chunk size each time. Is there any better/easier approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, I actually made a class for this a while back (non-ARC, but it still should work) available [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25258177/personal/RJRStreams.zip)

Example usage:

```
// in init
RJRStreamWriter myWriter = [[RJRStreamWriter alloc] initWithLocalFile:@"path/to/my/file" andAppend:NO];

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    static dispatch_queue_t asyncQueue;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
           asyncQueue = dispatch_queue_create("asyncQueue", NULL);
    });

    dispatch_async(asyncQueue, ^{
        // this method is optimized, and aggregates NSOutputStream, NSMutableData, and NSFileHandle
        [myWriter writeData:data];
    });
}
```

Comment: @Kamran I'm sorry, I accidentally forgot to include the files that were used in conjunction with the lib, try re-downloading it and tell me if it works...

Comment: Thanks Richard, to be able to compile your first code, I had to add similar code you sent me today. Thanks again.

Comment: Richard, Can you advise me for UPLOAD case? I changed a bit the same code to be able to upload a file. Now what would be the good approach to make the upload process be async? Thanks!

Comment: @Kamran this class does not support uploading a file at this time. You would need to create a socket or http post to your server.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, a couple of MBs is not huge. Doing it the same way for a couple of MBs would be absolutely fine. But if you do want to write to the file as you receive the data then you could use an `NSFileHandle`. Create one and then write data to it and then call `synchronizeFile` on it when you want to flush the data to disk. You could call `synchronizeFile` after say every 10MB have been written or something (and obviously at the end as well).

So e.g.:

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filename];
...
[fileHandle writeData:dataComeInFromURLConnection];
...
[fileHandle synchronizeFile];
```

Comment: My bad, I mean for couple hundred, like 300MB does your code handle the this big file?

Comment: Yes it would be fine for 300MB. Richard seems to have some code to do it as well, so either just go with using his class or roll your own like I did, just using an `NSFileHandle`.